# Azure web app application insights invalid data

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

I am using azure application insights on a web app. I was facing a issue with insights not showing at all. So troubleshooted and tried all the steps and resolved this issue. All the application insights were working fine but suddenly I started seeing GET/ in Performance=> Operation name. Please check the screenshot below,

[image]

I can see only one other operation in the insights and GET/. 
What does GET/ here means? And how could I get the application insights working?

Comment: GET is the http GET request that was served by your web application/api

Comment: Ok, but why does it not show any other requests like POST? Because this application is used extensively and has all kinds of requests coming in.